# TSQL select columns from rollup data columns

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have a rollup data table which stores data for daily counts, monthly counts and yearly counts. [image]

"rollup_type" designates if its a daily(1)/monthly(2)/yearly data(3). For a yearly record, both monthl/daily is null. For monthly record, daily is null.

I am trying to do a simple SELECT based on input start date and end date with no success. Here is what I tried which isn't working correctly.

```
declare @start_date datetime = '2013-02-01'
declare @enddate datetime = '2014-01-12'
   
select * from olr_rollup_data rd  
where ( rd.Year > DATEPART(YYYY, @start_date) or ( rd.Year = DATEPART(YYYY, @start_date) and ( (rd.Month > DATEPART(MM, @start_date) and rd.day is null) or (rd.MONTH = DATEPART(MM, @start_date) and rd.day >= DATEPART(DD, @start_date) ))))  
and   ( rd.Year < DATEPART(YYYY, @enddate) or ( rd.Year = DATEPART(YYYY, @enddate) and ( (rd.Month < DATEPART(MM, @enddate) and rd.day is null) or ( rd.MONTH = DATEPART(MM, @enddate) and rd.Day <= DATEPART(DD, @enddate) ))))
```

Basically, a generic select statement which will use combination of daily, monthly and yearly data from input dates. It should select days plus full month when input dates cover full month in between and so on.

I would appreciate if you help figure out correct select statement. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but why type YYYY instead of English (YEAR)? [The other lazy shortcuts (MM and DD) simply have to go...](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)

Comment: I will keep in mind. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are always a pain to work with, that is why it is nice to use the built in date time functions when available.  Sadly that won't work here, we have to figure out some tricks.

One way to work with dates as "numbers" is to multiply the year by 10000, the month by 100 and add these numbers to the day of the month.  This will give you an integer where the digits look like this

```
YYYYMMDD
```

While disjointed (there are a lot of integers you will never see) any integer with this representation has the same cardinality as the date it represents (those that are larger as a date are also larger as an integer.)

We can use this to solve your problem as follows:

```
DECLARE @startDate INTEGER = 20130201
DECLARE @endDate INTEGER = 20140112


SELECT * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT ((year*10000)+(ISNULL(month,0)*100)+ISNULL(day,0)) as dateInt, *
   FROM olr_rollup_date
 ) sub
 WHERE dateInt >= @startDate AND dateInt <= @endDate
```

This will include roll up row for the month that are "surrounded".  Since we default the null values to 0 a month null for May of 2014 would be 20140500.  This is greater than any date in April and less than any date June but smaller than any date in May.

Years will work in a similar way.

Comment: I dont know if it was clear from my question, but it should select full month only when its covered fully, otherwise just days. So for 2/2/2013 - 5/3/2013, it should have one record for each march, april and then remaining daily records for feb and may. Basically minimum records based on input dates period. Above query selects full month  even for partial month dates.

Comment: thanks for replying and helping, but above isnt working correctly as well. it wont select days when dayStart < dayEnd. Meaning, for 1/1/2013-3/1/2013, it doesnt select 1/3/2013 when it should.

Comment: @user704988 - Please see revised answer.